# How do you tell mathematica that a function F[x] is real valued?

Tags: functions

I am wondering how to tell Mathematica that a function, say `F[x]`, is a real-valued function so that, e.g., the `Conjugate` command will pass through it:

```
Conjugate[E^(-i k x)F[x]] = E^(i k x)F[x]
```

I tried to make a huge calculation using the `Conjugate` command, but without setting the arbitrary function `F[x]` as a real-valued function, the result is completely messy.

Comment: `ComplexExpand[Conjugate[E^(-I k x) F[x]]] // FullSimplify`

Comment: This is actually useful. Thank you. However, this does not work with derivatives of `F[x]`, i.e., the command `ComplexExpand[Conjugate[E^(-I k x) F'[x]]] // FullSimplify` gives `E^(I k x) Conjugate[F'[x]`.

Comment: `ComplexExpand[Conjugate[E^(-I k x) F'[x]]] // FullSimplify[#, Element[F'[x], Reals]] &`

Answer (score 2):

Use [assumptions](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Assuming.html):

```
Assuming[Element[F[_], Reals], 
  Conjugate[E^(-I k x) F[x]] // FullSimplify]

(*    E^(I Conjugate[k] Conjugate[x]) F[x]    *)
```

With several real-valued symbols:

```
Assuming[Element[F[_] | F'[_], Reals], 
  Conjugate[E^(-I k x) F[x] F'[x]] // FullSimplify]

(*    E^(I Conjugate[k] Conjugate[x]) F[x] F'[x]   *)
```

If we mention all symbols in this list of reals, then we recover the @BobHanlon's [`ComplexExpand`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexExpand.html) solution:

```
Assuming[Element[F[_] | F'[_] | k | x, Reals], 
  Conjugate[E^(-I k x) F[x] F'[x]] // FullSimplify]

(*    E^(I k x) F[x] F'[x]    *)
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm surprised, as Bob's answer works as you wish

[image]

However, if you don't want to use FullSimplify, you may redefine Conjugate[]

```
Unprotect[Conjugate]
Conjugate[f[x_]] := f[x]
Conjugate[Derivative[n_][f][x]] := Derivative[n][f][x]
Protect[Conjugate]
```

and then

```
Conjugate[Exp[I x] h[x] f'[x] f[x]]
```

gives

```
E^(-I Conjugate[x]) Conjugate[h[x]] f[x] Derivative[1][f][x]
```

Comment: I don’t think it’s a good idea to redefine internal functions. You never know what other internals depend on them and what assumptions are baked into the system.